# How can I save my databases when my xampp is not working?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

My xampp is not working and I don`t want to loose my databases. They are very Important. So, How can I save my databases? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of your mysql folder  `C:\path\to\xampp\mysql`, reinstall xampp, and then replace the new existing one with your old one.

Comment: Is It really works? Beacause my batabases are so important and I don`t want to loose them.

Comment: If you don't believe me, we can try to fix your database instead. What seems to be the problem with it? Do you not have access to PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, when I type in a google chrome`s URL "localhost/phpmyadmin" the error appears like this......

Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

So, I can`t access my databases. And they are very Important.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a client like dbeaver among others and backup manually the database into a unique sql file.